# Cannot accept alert in Microsoft Edge use Protractor

Tags: webdriver, protractor, microsoft-edge

I use API

`browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 10000).then(() => {
      browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
    });`

to leave page when alert is shown.
It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE11, but on Microsoft Edge, it cannot work.

I use Microsoft WebDriver Release 10586 (correct with windows buid 10586)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the supported list of [Microsoft Edge Webdriver APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-commands). It appears they have implemented the alert APIs per [W3C WebDriver specification support](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) but is available on "Insiders" version (see [Download page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) for Insiders version).